# How can I connect two different arrays and randomize them at the same time?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I am trying to connect 2 arrays but randomize them at the same time, for example:

Array 1: A,B,C,D,E
Array 2: 1,2,3,4,5

When I press the show button I want the letters to correspond to the numbers but I want them at random

C/3 , A/1 , E/5

Right now my source code randomizes my arrays but they are not in order, meaning I'm getting A/2, E/1, C,5. This is my code:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var randomLetter: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet weak var randomNumber: UIButton!

 @IBAction func showLetters(_ sender: Any) {

    let array1 = ["A","B","C","D","E"]


    let array2 = ["1","2","3","4","5"]


      let randomLetterGen = Int (arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array2.count)))
    randomLetter.text = array2 [randomLetterGen]

      let randomNumberGen = Int (arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array1.count)))
    randomNumber.text = array1 [randomNumberGen]

}
```

Comment: Just use the *same* random index for both arrays ...

Comment: you can also merge the two arrays into a touple (`(String, String)`), then randomize.  That way you can create a `randomize` method that is usable on any array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by using the same random index for both `array1` and `array2`.

Consider the below code:

```
let array1 = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
let array2 = ["1","2","3","4","5"]

let randomLetterGen = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array2.count)))
randomLetter.text = array2[randomLetterGen] //C
randomNumber.text = array1[randomLetterGen] //3
```

Comment: Happy to help..:)

Answer (score 0):

This code works

```
var array1 = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
    let array2 = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
    array2.forEach { (item) in
        array1.append(item)
    }
    print(array1.shuffle())
```